# Can "spacing out" repeated observations on an individual make them independent

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, correlation, nonparametric, independence

Heres a hypothetical example:

> Suppose we are interested in whether Sally eats more for breakfast or dinner. Consider two cases: 1) We observe her food choices on 5 days in a  row when she is training for a marathon. 2) We observe he food choices on 5 randomly chosen days of the year

I think the observations in the first case would not be independent: she is training for a marathon so perhaps she is eating large breakfasts every day

Are the observations in the second case independent? (because they have been randomized)

- One reason why maybe it doesn't is that the observations are perhaps still related: maybe Sally likes to eat a lot, and hence the observations are more likely to be of her eating large amounts of food.
- However... if she does like eating large amounts of food, this can also be interpreted as saying that her joint pdf, $f_{b,d}(b,d)$ puts a lot of density on large values of $b,d$. Which I don't think precludes our observations from being two totally separate realizations of the joint pdf. (note that $b,d$ denote breakfast and dinner)

Comment: There is not reason to expect a person's dietary choices on consecutive days are random. Training for a marathon or not, Sally may have a habit of alternating orange and apple juice for breakfast, or of buying a different kind of bread each weekend to use for toast the rest of the week, Etc, Etc. // A major reason for seeking independent observations is to get a random sample from the population; there is no way that re-arranging observations will make them more typical of the population. // So 5 randomly chosen days during the year would be best.

Comment: @BruceET Thank you. I understand that the dietary chocies from 5 consecutive days are likely not random, and that using 5 randomly chosen days would be best. However, the question is whether 5 randomly chosen days would qualify as independent observations?  That is, if someone had data from 5 (or 50) randomly chosen days and used a statistical test that assumes independent observations, would this test give accurate results? Or would the p-values be incorrect.

Comment: Random observations, all sampled from the same distribution, are independent. However, observations sampled on randomly chosen days from a time series may not be independent: for example if the time series has a secular or cyclical trend.